# what does mean experiment sessions of google optimize?

Tags: google-analytics, google-optimize

I used google optimize to create patterns A-D and set the specific gravity to all 25%. For this test I have created four patterns of form entry screens and would like to see the conversion rate. But...

he numbers for the experiment sessions were 499, 384, 497 and 429. 　 There was quite a wide range, but If I look the data of same experiment at google analytics, the number of unique pageviews is They were 317, 318, 307 and 281. The numbers are less than the experiment sessions. It's also less wide. Why does differences appear? What is the definition of each? Also, is it possible to see the numbers of unique users?

If you know of any, please let me know.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related

Comment: Is the date range used in GA the same as from Google Optimize?

Answer (score 3):

Experiment sessions are sessions where users were part of the experiment and saw either one of the variant pages or the original page.

Regarding the discrepancies between what is reported in Google Optimize and Google Analytics, they occur mainly because of 2 reasons:

1. Not all users who view the tested pages end up in the experiment, thus they are counted in GA but not counted in Google Optimize. This happens for a multitude of reasons but the most common one is anti flickering snippet not firing. When this occurs, the page will not be part of the experiment and Google Optimize will not count it as an experiment session while the "Unique Pageview" metric will still update in GA.
2. Data freshness. Data is first sent to GA and from there, after about 4 hours is pushed to Google Optimize, thus, in GA, when the experiment is running, this might cause discrepancies.

You could check this article for a more detailed explanation: https://analyticshelp.io/blog/google-optimize-redirect-test-qa/